# Método onAttach Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Galera, estou tendo problema em como utilizar o onattach. Tenho uma view que é setada visible quando um botão é acionado. Gostaria que essa View Sumisse ao final de uma operação de um fragment. Olhem o Código que fará mais sentido.

Na Activity:

```
    private View layoutProgress;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    layoutProgress = findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);

    layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Quando o Botão é acinonado:

```
    fragment.getInstance().printScreen();(Função de Tirar foto no fragment)
    layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

No Fragment:

Executa o necessário e gostaria que sumisse o layoutProgress.

Como fazer isso?
Desculpa a edição, ainda estou aprendendo a formatar melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Achei um jeito, Vou postar caso alguém precise

depois do executa o código no fragment colocar esse código:

```
    Activity act = getActivity();
    if (act == null) return;
    View layoutProgress = findViewById(R.id.layout_progress);
```

Comment: Eduardo, seria bom se pudesse acrescentar essas informações na sua pergunta. Esse espaço é reservado para respostas.